# How to get title from a href?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've this tag structure:

```
<td class="team team-a "><a href="/teams/austria/sportverein-mattersburg/163/" title="Mattersburg">Mattersburg</a></td>
```

I'm trying to get the `title` attribute with this regex:

```
return Regex.Replace(href, "<a[^>]*?title=\"([^\"]*?\"[^>]*?>", "");
```

where `href` variable is the content `<td>`, seems that the regex fails, why?

Comment: You are just missing a closed parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax error, but that's not the main problem. As you're replacing, you should remove *anything but the title*. So you should remove everything before the title itself and anything after. For example,

```
return Regex.Replace(href, ".*title=\"|\".*", "");
```

Less specific solution, in case there're some other tags with the title attribute, and you need only the title of `<a>`:

```
.*<a[^>]*?title=\"|\".*
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an alternative, take a look at the HtmlAgilityPack:

```
var html = "<td class=\"team team-a\"><a href=\"/teams/austria/sportverein-mattersburg/163/\" title=\"Mattersburg\">Mattersburg</a></td>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a") [0];
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["Title"].Value);
```

Of course RegEx should be faster. But in my experience, the HtmlAgilityPack is much easier to use and much more forgiving when it comes to irregularities and invalid html.